# Error testing OGRE's tutorial code. incomplete type 'Ogre::MeshManager'

Tags: gcc, ogre

I am trying to go through the OGRE's [tutorial](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Basic%20Tutorial%202) #2.
I successfully went trough the first part.

My problem is when I try to compile I get an error in this method:

```
void TutorialApplication::createScene(void){

      mSceneMgr->setAmbientLight(Ogre::ColourValue(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
      mSceneMgr->setShadowTechnique(Ogre::SHADOWTYPE_STENCIL_ADDITIVE);

      Ogre::Entity* entNinja = mSceneMgr->createEntity("Ninja", "ninja.mesh");
      entNinja->setCastShadows(true);
      Ogre::SceneNode* headNode = mSceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode("HeadNode");
      headNode->attachObject(entNinja);

      Ogre::Plane plane(Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_Y, 0);

      Ogre::MeshManager::getSingleton().createPlane("ground", Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
        plane, 1500, 1500, 20, 20, true, 1, 5, 5, Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_Z);
      Ogre::Entity* entGround = mSceneMgr->createEntity("GroundEntity", "ground");
      mSceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode()->attachObject(entGround);
      entGround->setCastShadows(false);
      entGround->setMaterialName("Examples/Rockwall");
}
```

The error I get is:

> error: incomplete type 'Ogre::MeshManager' used in nested name
>   specifier
>        Ogre::MeshManager::getSingleton().createPlane("ground", Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,

Which is weird, because apparently anybody is having problems with this tutorial. I am using Ogre 1.9 which I compiled in my machine (Ubuntu 14.04 x64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following include into your code, it should work. The reason for your issue might be, that the respective tutorial has not been updated to match Ogre 1.9.

```
#include <OgreMeshManager.h>
```

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thanks.